# Schwarzschild Christoffel Symbol Problem

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Schwarzchild metric is static, none of its components change over time. Curiously, basis vector $e_r$ does change over time. If we differentiate $e_r$ with respect to time and take the time component of the derivative we get a non zero value, i.e, $\Gamma_{10}^0$ is not $0$.

So, if $e_r$ changes over time, how come $g_{rr}$ remain static, given that $g_{rr} = e_r\cdot e_r$?

Answer (score 4):

We need to quantify the meaning of "changes with time".
There's two ways to define changes of a vector field with respect to another one.
One of them is given by the covariant derivative, which you have calculated:

$$ \nabla_{\partial_{t}}\partial_{r} = \Gamma^{\lambda}_{tr}\partial_{\lambda}$$

and have correctly noticed that only $\lambda=t$ contributes to the above, yielding:

$$ \nabla_{\partial_{t}}\partial_{r} = \frac{1}{2}g^{tt}g_{tt,r}\partial_{t}$$

However, this does not translate in any way to the claim that $g_{rr}$ changes with time. The only thing it says is that the coordinate vector field $\partial_{r}$ is not geodesic (*c.f.* the meaning of the parallel transport and geodesics).

The other way of quantifying the change of a vector field with respect to another one is through Lie derivative:

$$ \mathcal{L}_{\partial_{t}}\partial_{r} = [\partial_{t},\partial_{r}] = 0$$

Which means that the coordinate vector field is Lie-transported along $\partial_{t}$ (transported along the integral curves of one-parameter diffeomorphism group of the vector field $\partial_{t}$,  $\mathcal{G}^{\partial_{t}}$).

Note that this still doesn't necessarily mean that the metric component changes with time. The only way to meaningfully define **the metric's rate of change with time** is to calculate the Lie derivative:

$$ \mathcal{L}_{\partial_{t}}g = \mathcal{L}_{\partial_{t}}(g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}\otimes dx^{\nu})$$

which you can find to vanish.

**A better answer**

We're posing the question: how does the four length of the $\partial_{r}$ coordinate vector field change in time?

$$f  := g_{rr}=g(\partial_{r},\partial_{r}) = (1 - \frac{2M}{r})^{-1}$$

Since the above is a scalar field, to calculate its derivative along a vector field, we can equivalently use:

$$ \partial_{t}f = \mathcal{L}_{\partial_{t}}f = \nabla_{\partial_{t}}f$$

**The first equivalent formula**

In the first case one we calculate trivially

$$ \partial_{t}f = \partial_{t}\big{(}(1 - \frac{2M}{r})^{-1}\big{)} = 0 $$

This should already settle the matter, but we can calculate the other two as an exercise.
In the second and the third one, we use the commutativity of the covariant/Lie derivative with contractions.

**The second equivalent formula**

$$ \mathcal{L}_{\partial_{t}}f = \mathcal{L}_{\partial_{t}}(g(\partial_{r},\partial_{r})) = (\mathcal{L}_{\partial_{t}}g)(\partial_{r},\partial_{r}) +  g(\mathcal{L}_{\partial_{t}}\partial_{r}, \partial_{r}) +  g(\partial_{r},\mathcal{L}_{\partial_{t}}\partial_{r})$$

The first term is what I've mentioned before - the metric tensor is Lie-transported along the flow of $\partial_{t}$. If you need help proving that, here's a quick calculation, using the fact that the Lie derivative (also the covariant derivative) obeys the Leibniz rule:

$$\mathcal{L}_{\partial_{t}}g= \mathcal{L}_{\partial_{t}}(g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}\otimes dx^{\nu}) = \mathcal{L}_{\partial_{t}}(g_{\mu\nu})dx^{\mu}\otimes dx^{\nu} + g_{\mu\nu}(\mathcal{L}_{\partial_{t}}dx^{\mu})\otimes dx^{\nu} + g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}\otimes (\mathcal{L}_{\partial_{t}}dx^{\nu}) = 0 $$

It vanishes because:
$\mathcal{L}_{\partial_{t}}(g_{\mu\nu}) = \partial_{t}g_{\mu\nu}=0$

where the Lie derivative reduces to a partial derivative because it acts on a scalar field.

Meanwhile the other Lie derivatives can be evaluated by virtue of Cartan's magic formula:

$$ \mathcal{L}_{X}\omega = d(\iota_{X}\omega) + \iota_{X}d\omega $$

$$ \mathcal{L}_{\partial_{t}}dx^{\mu} = d(dx^{\mu}(\partial_{t})) + \iota_{\partial_{t}}d^{2}x^{\mu} = d(\delta^{\mu}_{t}) = 0 $$

**The third equivalent formula**

$$\nabla_{\partial_{t}}f = \nabla_{\partial_{t}}(g(\partial_{r},\partial_{r})) = (\nabla_{\partial_{t}}g)(\partial_{r},\partial_{r}) + g(\nabla_{\partial_{t}}\partial_{r}, \partial_{r}) + g(\partial_{r},\nabla_{\partial_{t}}\partial_{r})  = 0 $$

where we use the metric compatibility of the covariant derivative and the fact that $\nabla_{\partial_{t}}\partial_{r} = \frac{1}{2}g^{tt}g_{tt,r}\partial_{t} $  and $\partial_{t}$ is orthogonal to $\partial_{r}$.

Comment: Thank you. But my actual problem is, how can g_rr stay unchanged since it’s the dot product of e_r and e_r, while the covariant derivative of e_r is non zero. Can you please address that part?

Comment: In the simplest terms, there are different types of derivatives - there's the covariant derivative that measures deviation from parallel transport, there's the Lie derivative which measures the change of a tensor field under the pushforward along a vector's field flow, there's the Fermi-Walker derivative etc. There is no contradiction between $\partial_{r}$ being non-geodesic and its length $g_{rr}=g(\partial_{r}, \partial_{r})$ being constant wrt. to coordinate time $t$. The latter is exactly $\partial_{t}g_{rr}=\partial_{t}(g(\partial_{r}, \partial_{r}))=\partial_{t}(\frac{r}{r+2M})=0$

Comment: I'm writing a better answer under my original answer. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got this.
$$g_{rr} = e_r\cdot e_r$$
$$\Rightarrow \partial_tg_{rr}
=2e_r\cdot\partial_te_r$$
Now, since the time derivative of $e_r$ is solely in the direction of $t$, it is orthogonal to $e_r$, therefore the RHS is $0$, equating the LHS.